# Polymer Databinding Attribute Works Without $ - Side Effect?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

[From Polymer's Anatomy of a data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding)

> To bind to a property, use the property name in attribute form (dash-case not camelCase), as described in Property name to attribute name mapping:
>
> `<my-element my-property="{{hostProperty}}">`
>
> To bind to an attribute instead, use the attribute name followed by $:
>
> `<a href$="{{hostProperty}}">`

But in my code, `<div style="background-image: [[getImage(index)]]" class="image-show"></div>` works perfectly without `$`.

Why is this when `style` is a attribute and not a property(there is no `style` property defined in the `Polymer({})` constructor). Am I working off of a side effect?

Answer (score 1):

Style is a standard HTML attribute. The polymetric way to bind to a style is to use

```
<div style$="[[myStyle]]">
```

What you're doing is using a standard style tag with a data-bind to a style property.

On the page you linked, scroll down to the section labeled: **Native properties that don't support property binding** and you'll see the other attributes that you have to use `$=` with.

Comment: Yes, you repeated what I said in the original post. But this doesn't answer the question why I can do so successfully- contrary to documentation, and if it is working off of a side effect. Also, properties in Polymer belong to the property object in the constructor. By default, not the html attributes(unless `reflectToAttribute` set to true).